# How to reverse the Fibonacci Series in c without using an Array?

Tags: c

I'm Learning C right now. We have been asked by our instructor to learn how to code the fibonacci series. I have found codes in the internet and it was right. Now another problem given to us was the output of the series must be reversed without using an array or functions, now I'm tryong to figure it out but still I can't get it.

Can someone please give me the code to reverse the output. Thank You!

Comment: SO is not here to do your homework for you. Show what you've tried, where *exactly* your stuck and somebody might help.

Comment: Hi There! This is my first question in this site or probably I've never been posting any questions on sites like this before, sorry for that. Thanks for your advice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to calculate the Fibonacci numbers and remember the last two numbers calculated. Do the inverse operations and print the numbers:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("number of Fibonacci numbers: ");
    int n;
    scanf_s( "%d",&n );
    if ( n > 47 )
        n = 47;

    long int f1 = 0;
    long int f2 = 1;
    for ( int i = 2; i < n; i ++ ) // calculate the first n Fibonacci numbers
    {
        long int s = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = s;
    }

    while ( f1 >= 0 )              // do inverse operations and print Fibonacci numbers
    {
        printf( "%ld ", f2 );
        long int t = f2 - f1;
        f2 = f1;
        f1 = t;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great! It solved my problem. by the way I noticed that you are using "long int" in declaring variables, what does it mean? what is its difference between "int". Cause I did whats in your code except "long int" still gives me the correct answer.

Comment: Oh I see. Now I understand. Thanks a lot Rabbid76, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using recursion. Call the next recursive call and print the result after that. It will give you the result.

```
void printFibonacci(int);

int main(){

    int n;

    printf("Enter the range of the Fibonacci series: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");

    printFibonacci(n);
    printf("%d %d ",1,0);
    return 0;
}

void printFibonacci(int n){

    static long int first=0,second=1;
    int sum;

    if(n>0){
         sum = first + second;
         first = second;
         second = sum;

         printFibonacci(n-1);
         printf("%ld ",sum);
    }

}
```

**EDIT** without using functions or arrays
You can calculate the nth number in the Fibonacci series beforehand and subtract it with the previous value to get the next value.

```
int prev=0;
int next=1;
for( i=0; i<n; i++ )
{
    sum = prev+next;
    prev = next;
    next = sum;
}
do
{
    printf("%ld ",sum);
    int k = sum-prev;
    sum = prev;
    prev = k;
} 
while( sum!=0 );
printf("0");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still can't use Functions. I'll just try to understand your codes and make a revision if I can. Or if you had any other way please tell me. Thank You!

Comment: @LMAOCoding edited the answer

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help Rakish Nair. That also helped me a lot.